# Approximate functional equation of the L function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, l-functions

I was reading a paper on Selberg's central limit theorem for the classical automorphic $L$ functions attached to primitive holomorphic cusp form $f$. I can not understand the following equation.

\begin{align*}
&\int_{T}^{2T} L(f,\sigma+it)M(f,\sigma+it) dt\\
=& \sum_{n\leq T}\frac{\lambda_f(n)}{n^{\sigma}}\sum_{m<T^{\epsilon}}\frac{a(m)\mu(m)\lambda_f(m)}{m^{\sigma}} \int_{T}^{2T} (mn)^{-it} dt +O(T^{1/2+\epsilon}) \\
=& T+O(T^{1/2+\epsilon})
\end{align*}

Why does the second line of the equation hold from the first line using the approximate functional equation for the $L$ functions?

The Dirichlet series $M(f,\sigma+it)$ is given by
$M(f,\sigma+it)=\sum_{n}\frac{\mu(n)a(n)\lambda_f(n)}{n^s}$, where
\begin{align*}
a(n)= \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } n<T^{\epsilon} \\
0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put the series expressions for the factors in the integral and look at the part with $n,m$ large (bigger than these $T$'s).  pull the sums outside and you see that what you need to show is that certain exponential integrals are small (less than the $T$ errors).  the value of $\sigma $ is important.

Comment: @tomos Thank you so much. Yes, you're right the value of $1/2<\sigma<1$ was given in that paper. But where the approximate functional equation of the L-function was used?

Comment: oh sorry, you're right i overlooked that, so maybe i'm talking nonsense in the first comment. (but also maybe not, maybe you still have to split the $m$ sum.)

the approximate functional equation for $L$-functions splits the $n$ sum into a $\leq T$ part and a $>T$ part.  the part with $>T$ should go into the error - that's what you have to show.  

i would move forward by making sure you can write down a clean statement of the approximate functional equation $L$-functions and then integrating the whole expression.

Comment: @tomos Thanks. Sorry for the last comment. But how can they have the main term from it?

Comment: The main term comes from the $m=n=1$ case, while the others are absorbed by the remainder due to oscillation.

Comment: @TravorLZH Thanks!

Comment: @tomos The approximate functional equation given in Theorem 5.3 of [Iwanice-Kowalski](https://www.ams.org/books/coll/053/) do not have the expression $n\leq T$, how can one split the sum into $a\leq T$ and $a>T$ using that theorem?

Comment: you only need the functional equation for $L$-functions.  write it down cleanly and see what happens when you try to integrate it.  (the functional equation is exactly a sum over $n\leq T$ and a remainder term).  you don't need to split the $m$ sum (this is just the definition of $a(m)$).

Comment: The functional equation for the $L$ functions is $\Lambda(f,n)=q^{s/2}\gamma_f(s)L(f,s)=\varepsilon(f)\overline{\Lambda(f,s)}$. Is this the equation you're referring to?

Comment: argh sorry, was a poor comment.  you need: the approximate functional equation for an $L$-function, without a weight.  theorem 5.3 of iwaniec-kowalski is weighted.  i don't know where there's a reference for it without a weight:/

Comment: Thanks! I was confused with this one. Thanks for your clarification. I couldn't find a reference either. If you find one please let me know.

Comment: googling it gives this for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3716.pdf.  maybe theorem 1.2 is what you want? i'm not sure

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it seems clear to me now. I think I need to put $m=0$ in Theorem 1.2.

Comment: yep:) what's to take away from this discussion is: you want to integrate these series but you're outside the region of convergence.  but the approximate functional equation let's you have something "similar" to the whole dirichlet series, and you can integrate this instead.

Comment: An unweighted version of approximate functional equation is available as Lavrik's general theorem in §3.7.2 of Karatsuba's _Complex Analysis in Number Theory_.